# Why the first parameter is type of User why not string ? Typescript can anyone explain me why when

Tags: typescript, function, generics, types

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
};
function createAction<T>(type: string) {
  return (payload: T) => ({ type, payload })
}

const createUser = createAction<User>("noob");

const result = createUser({ id: 1, title: "sdf" })
console.log(result.payload)
```

when I call createUser the parameter it required type of User not string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the function:

```
function createAction<T>(type: string) {
  return (payload: T) => ({ type, payload })
}
```

This function returns *another function*. This returned function is `(payload: T) => ({ type, payload })`. Notice that it is annotated to accept a `payload` of type `T`.

So, in `const createUser = createAction<User>("noob");`, `T` is `User` and therefore `createUser` takes a `User`.